# Creating a single column page layout in SharePoint 2010

Tags: formatting

I have been grappling with this seemingly basic task for the past hour and getting increasingly frustrated.

I have created a basic SharePoint site which by default gives me a left and right column, I want the left column to span 100% percent with no right hand column. I am not trying to hide the left menu - this is fine as it is.

I wrongly assumed SharePoint would offer some sort of "Choose your site layout" screen which allows you to choose, 1 column, 2 column, 3 column etc - but it seems not.

Any web searches I do are telling me to include JavaScript code etc etc - I can't believe this is such a hard to accomplish task??!

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this by:

- Opening SharePoint designer
- Loading the site
- Going to 'Site Pages'
- New > 'Web Part page'
- From here you can select the page layout you want (one of the options being single column)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is SharePoint Designer. I'll assume that you're using a non-Publishing site.

- Install SharePoint Designer on your client machine Create a new Site
  (e.g. a 'Blank Site')
- Open the site in SharePoint Designer Edit the
  page (e.g. default.aspx) in "Advanced Mode".
- Change the HTML to the
  structure you want.
- Save.
- Check-in your changes.
- If you want to
  reused this site as a template, go to Site Settings and save it as a
  template.

If you're using a publishing page, life is similar, but you'll need to edit the Page Layout (found in the _catalogs/Masterpage folder in SharePoint Designer's view of your site). You can tell if you're using a publishing page if the homepage of your site contains a `/pages/` in the url.

Comment: Thanks for this - I was using SharePoint designer. The problem is that when editing the code it is not evident where the change needs to be made. Also, large portions of the code are prevented from being edited to maintain xhtml strict. I was hoping not to have to resort to code level changes (my understanding was that SharePoint should reduce the need to modify code and provide  a wizard based configurable layer, however I'm increasingly starting to doubt that). Thanks for your answer, I have pasted another one below which achieved the desired result for me.

Answer (score 1):

I read your reply. You can actually do this directly from the SharePoint UI, by creating a new Web Part page.

If for some reason you need to do it on an existing two column page, you can follow this article:
http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2009/10/16/a-method-to-customize-web-part-zones/